# Can I render on both CUDA and OpenCL?

Tags: rendering, opencl

I have a vega 56 and a gtx 1060 both render just fine on their own but i would love to use them in unison if at all possible otherwise i will have to figure out how to sell my 1060 and buy an RX 590. Im willing to try 3rd party programs and plugins. Im using Blender 2.8 Beta ATM.